# PolynomialRemainder memory

Tags: polynomials, memory

This calculation makes the kernel crash because it needs so much memory.  Thoughts on how to get around this?

```
PolynomialRemainder[1+x^267910657,1+x+x^20+x^32, x, Modulus->2]
```

Comment: `PolynomialMod[1 + x^267910657, {1 + x + x^20 + x^32, 2}]`

Comment: I have to ask, where did this come from? It is not something I would expect to do, so I'm curious.

Comment: We'll look into improving on this.

Comment: I get an error message `CoefficientList::lrgexp: Exponent is out of bounds for function CoefficientList. >>` (v9.0.1 Mac).

Answer (score -2):

I think, "Fermat little theorem" can work on your problem. Also, you can find it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)

Comment: Could you amplify this answer and show how your suggestion would work in *Mathematica*? It's especially puzzling that the reference you give makes no mention at all of polynomials.

Comment: Taking @whuber's comment a step further, as polynomials, x^p and x are by no means equivalent modulo p.

Comment: Yes. you are right. if katie tries to find some solution, then it runs in my opinion. Because Fermat Little Theorem reduce the exponent of `x`. So, the theorem makes it easy. Unfortunately, we don't know the main problem.